# Vue TypeError: reduce is not a function

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am using `Vue.js` with `Typescript` and I would like to use `reduce` in order to sum each of `desktopCnt` and `mobileCnt` so that I can display the total numbers.

There is an `array`,`deviceCount`, which contains as below.

```json
[
    {
       "_id":{
          "device":1
       },
       "mobileCnt":451
    },
    {
       "_id":{
          "device":0
       },
       "desktopCnt":210
    },
    {
       "_id":{
          "device":2
       },
       "mobileCnt":88
    },
    {
       "_id":{
          "device":10
       },
       "mobileCnt":57
    }
]
```

This is what I coded

```js
 <template>
   <span>
    PC :
    {{ deviceCount.reduce((r, a) => (r += a.desktopCnt), 0) }}

    Mobile :
    {{ deviceCount.reduce((a, { desktopCnt }) => a + mobileCnt, 0) }}
   </span>
 </template>
```

**script** to fetch data

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import { DeviceCount } from '../../components/models';

export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      deviceCount: [] as Array<DeviceCount>,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.initData();
  },
  methods: {
    async initData() {
      this.getDeviceCount()
        .then((response) => {
          this.deviceCount = response;
        })
        .catch((error) => (this.deviceCount = error.data));
    },

    async getDeviceCount() {
      const url = 'url';
      const ret = await axios.get(url);
      const item = ret.data.results;

      for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        if (item[i]._id.device === 0) item[i].desktopCnt = item[i].uniqueEvents;
      }

      item.forEach(
        (element: {
          _id: { device: number };
          mobileCnt: number;
          uniqueEvents: any;
        }) => {
          if (element._id.device !== 0) {
            element.mobileCnt = 0;
            element.mobileCnt += element.uniqueEvents;
          }
        }
      );

      return item;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

*I edited `interface`*
**interface DeviceCount**

```
interface DeviceCount {
    _id: {
      device: string;
    };
    avgPrice: number;
    avgQuantity: number;
    buyRatio: number;
    goodsCnt: number;
    quantity: number;
    revenue: number;
    totalEvents: number;
    uniqueEvents: number;
    users: number;
    mobileCnt: number;
    desktopCnt: number;
}
```

`console.log(item)` in `script`
[image]

I am trying two different(?) ways, but I still get this error :

> TypeError: _vm.deviceCount.reduce is not a function

Could you let me know where this error comes from?

Comment: How do you define the `deviceCount` in your script? please share the whole code

Comment: `deviceCount` is not an array. I'd willing to bet that it is an undefined or number

Comment: @captain-yossarian I also checked using `Array.isArray(deviceCount)` and the result is `true`

Comment: I think you should do something like `deviceCount.results.reduce((r, a)`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Oh so I should add `results` behind?

Comment: @Uheny I think so

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim But `deviceCount` does not have `results` inside

Comment: It should, if it respects the interface definition, please log the response and give us the output

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I added an image of `console.log(item)`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Like you said, the `interface` won't match with the `item` which I checked in log, so I changed the `interface` into `DeviceCount` Then I got no errors, but still it displays `NaN`..

Answer (score 0):

Don't put long javascript expressions inside the template, create computed properties to do the job then render these properties :

```
 <template>
   <span>
    PC :
    {{ desktopCount}}

    Mobile :
    {{ mobileCount }}
   </span>
 </template>
```

then in script :

```
export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      deviceCount: [] as Array<DeviceCount>,
    };
  },
computed:{
   desktopCount(){
   return this.deviceCount.reduce((r, a) => (r += (+a.desktopCnt ?? 0) ), 0)
   },
  mobileCount(){

  return this.deviceCount.reduce((a, { mobileCnt}) => a=a + (+mobileCnt ?? 0), 0)
  }

}
...
```

`a.property ?? 0`  means return 0 if the a.property is undefined or null to avoid the `NaN` result

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it gives me this error in `computed` : > Property 'deviceCount' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, unknown, unknown, unknown, Readonly<Record<never, any>>>`

Comment: what about trying it directly in template `{{deviceCount.reduce((r, a) => (r += (+a.desktopCnt ?? 0) ), 0)}}`

Comment: I just tried, but it won't be rendered then at all..